# How to order GitLab tags from latest to oldest

Tags: git, gitlab, tags

I have cloned recursively a repo from GitLab and then got the tags of the submodules by using the following command:

```
git submodule foreach git tag -l
```

So as an example. I have the following submodule (components), AccltrInterLckDet listed along with all of its tags:

```
Entering 'components/AccltrInterLckDet'
01.01.20210702.001
01.02.202203.001
beagledaimler.02.202211.001
legendgold.02.202210.001
octanegold.02.202210.001
titanium.02.202210.001
titanium.02.202211.001
```

Is there a way to order the tags from latest to oldest? As reference for that component when I go into GitLab and sort the tags by "Updated date", I get the following order:

```
titanium.02.202211.001 
beagledaimler.02.202211.001 
titanium.02.202210.001, legendgold.02.202210.001 
octanegold.02.202210.001 
01.02.202203.001 
01.01.20210702.001
```

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, you want the tags not just from one module, but from all of them, interspersed together by dates starting with the most recent?

Comment: Or do you just want them from most recent to oldest in each submodule?

Comment: From most recent to oldest in each submodule

Comment: Then my answer your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `taggerdate` sort key to sort your tags, and add `-` in front to make it sort them in reverse order:

```
git tag --sort=-taggerdate -l
```

so for all your submodules, that would be

```
git submodule foreach git tag --sort=-taggerdate -l
```

Comment: Note that this only works for *annotated* tags, and then sorts them by *tag* date, which is not necessarily the same as a version sort.

Comment: @torek that's true. For non-annotated tags, `--sort=-committerdate` could be an ok approximation, but for a repo with mixed tags, I didn't find a way to mix the two.